# Make every combination of multiple arrays without repeating items in each array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, cartesian-product

Let me says this up front, I am not trying to get every combination.

I am trying to get every combination of 6 players per team without each player being on a new team with another player from their original team.
example

```
$team1 = "John, Joey, Steve, Lee";
$team2 = "Tom, Alex, Billy";
$team3 = "Clint";
$team4 = "Alan, Jerry";
...
$team10 = "James, Corey, Paul, Benny";
```

John and Joey can not be in the future combinations; Tom and Billy cannot be in any future combinations together. But I am trying to get every combination of 1 player from each of the 10 teams.
I have all ten teams in an associative array $team

I have been trying to use this function but I think I am on the wrong track.

```
function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
    if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }

    // get combinations from subsequent arrays
    $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);

    $result = array();

    // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $result[] = is_array($t) ? 
                array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                array($v, $t);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(
    combinations(
        array(
            $team[1],
            $team[2],
            $team[3],
            $team[4],
            $team[5],
            $team[6],
            $team[7],
            $team[8],
            $team[9],
            $team[10]
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: so $team1,$team2,...... have players in commmon

Comment: No I've eliminated any duplicates from the entire associative array. Each Team has different players. But in their new teams they cannot  be on a team with their original teammates.

Comment: What are you doing with duplicate names? For example, if there are two people named "Chris"

Comment: They've been previously eliminated. Only one Chris is allowed to play, they second Chris has to go home.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
        <?php
        $team1 = array("John", "Joey", "Steve", "Lee");
        $team2 = array("Tom", "Alex", "Billy");
        $team3 = array("Clint","a","c");
        $team4 = array("Alan", "Jerry");
        $team5 = array("John1", "Joey1", "Steve1", "Lee1");
        $team6 = array("Tom1", "Alex1", "Billy1");
        $team7 = array("Clint1","b","d");
        $team8 = array("Alan1", "Jerry1");
        $team9 = array("John2", "Joey2", "Steve2", "Lee2");
        $team10 = array("Tom2", "Alex2", "Billy2");


        $noTeams = 10;

        //$noNewTeams = 10;

        $membersPicked = array();
        $teamsDone = 0; // the whole team picked up
        $teamMemsDone = array();



        for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
            $teamName = "team".$i;  
            $teamMemsDone["$teamName"] = 0;

        }






        $n=1;

        //for($n=1; $n<$noNewTeams+1; $n++) {
        //    $index = $n+1;

        do {

            unset($teamPicked);
            unset($newTeam);
            $newTeam = array();
            $teamPicked = array(); 

            //for($i=0; $i<6; $i++) {
            do {
                // pick up 6 team members for new team

                foreach($teamPicked as $key=>$value) {
                    //echo "$key => $value .... <br>";
                }


                do {
                    $teamNo = rand(1,$noTeams);
                }while(in_array($teamNo, $teamPicked) );

                array_push($teamPicked, $teamNo);

                $teamName = "team".$teamNo;
                $memsOfTeam = count($$teamName);

                $thisTeam = $$teamName;

                //echo "$teamNo, $teamName, $memsOfTeam <br/>";
                $member = "";
                $memberName = "";
                $noOfTimes = 0;
                do {
                    $member = array_rand($$teamName,1);
                    $memberName = $thisTeam[$member];
                    $noOfTimes ++;
                }while(in_array($memberName, $membersPicked) && $noOfTimes < $memsOfTeam);

                if($memberName != "") {
                    //echo $thisTeam[$member] ." <br/>";
                    array_push($membersPicked, $memberName);

                    $teamMemsDone["$teamName"] += 1; 

                    if($teamMemsDone["$teamName"] > $memsOfTeam) {
                        $teamsDone ++;

                        echo "$teamName - done. <br/>";
                    }

                    array_push($newTeam, $memberName);
                }


               // echo " new team members selected = " . count($newTeam) . "<br/>";


            } while(count($newTeam)<6);

            $newTeamName = "newTeam".$n;
            $$newTeamName = $newTeam;
            echo $newTeamName ."<br/>";

            $n++;


            foreach($$newTeamName as $key=>$val){
                echo "$key => $val <br/>";
            }
            echo "<br/>";

            echo $teamsDone ."<br/>";

        }while($teamsDone < $noTeams);

        //}


        ?>
```

Comment: I'll look at this closer when I get home,but it looks like this will yield only 10 results. I'm looking for all teams I can make without any current teammates being together on a new team.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond, but I've been researching this a bit more and It turns out I am wanting a Cartesian Product. But I  Love this Random function you made here. That's good stuff! I don't understand what each line is doing could you explain section of function is doing please?